# How to Open Detail Fragment on Click of the ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I, have implemented view-pager in my project. Now I want when I click on particular view-pager It will open a new Detail Fragment. Where according to that Image Slider information is available.

Here is my code:

Adapter Code:

```
public class SliderImageAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter<SliderImageAdapter.SliderAdapterVH>{

    public List<Banner> bannerList;
    public Context context;

    public SliderImageAdapter(Context context, List<Banner> bannerList) {

        this.bannerList = bannerList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SliderAdapterVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_slider_myshop, parent, false);
        return new SliderAdapterVH(inflate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SliderAdapterVH viewHolder, final int position) {

        Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                .load(bannerList.get(position).getmSliderImage())
                .fitCenter()
                .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bannerList.size();
    }

    public int getItemPosition (Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    class SliderAdapterVH extends SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder {

        View itemView;
        ImageView imageViewBackground;
        ImageView imageGifContainer;

        public SliderAdapterVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageViewBackground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_auto_image_slider);
            imageGifContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_gif_container);
            this.itemView = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Home Fragment Code:

```java
private SliderImageAdapter sliderImageAdapter;
private List<Banner> bannerList;

sliderMyshop = view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
sliderMyshop.setSliderAdapter(sliderImageAdapter);
sliderMyshop.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.WORM); //set indicator animation by using SliderLayout.IndicatorAnimations. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
sliderMyshop.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
sliderMyshop.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
sliderMyshop.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
sliderMyshop.startAutoCycle();

mFirestore.collection("Banner").orderBy("mSliderImage", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        assert documentSnapshots != null;

        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                String doc_id = doc.getDocument().getId();
                Banner banner = doc.getDocument().toObject(Banner.class).withDocId(doc_id);
                bannerList.add(doc.getNewIndex(), banner);
                sliderImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED) {
                String docID = doc.getDocument().getId();
                Banner changedModel = doc.getDocument().toObject(Banner.class).withDocId(docID);
                if (doc.getOldIndex() == doc.getNewIndex()) {
                    // Item changed but remained in same position
                    bannerList.set(doc.getOldIndex(), changedModel);
                } else {
                    // Item changed and changed position
                    bannerList.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
                    bannerList.add(doc.getNewIndex(), changedModel);
                }
            } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED) {
                // remove
                bannerList.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
            }
            sliderImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

Now I, want to open another fragment on click of a particular image. According to position. Please guide me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Onclicklistener` on `imageview` in `onBindViewHolder` method:

```java
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});
```

Then you need to separate `Activity` and call that activity in `onclick` method  just like this:

```java
context.startActivity(new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class))
```

You can also add fragment to this `DetailActivity`.